# Storing the result of a SELECT statement in single string using SQLite3 in C

Tags: c, arrays, sqlite, char, calloc

I'm curious if you can store the result of a SQL statement as a single "string" in C. I'm working on a networks project where I need to be able to query the number of available seats in a plane and have the server return it to the client in a single string. I'm a Java programmer and the lack of strings in C is really stressing me out.

```
static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    printf("%s ", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}

static void querySeatsAvailable(sqlite3 *db, int flightNumber) {
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int  dbCheck;
    char *sql;

    switch(flightNumber) {
        case 1: 
            sql = "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" \
                "SELECT seat_number FROM plane1 WHERE is_available=1;";
            break;      
    }

    // Execute SQL statement 
    dbCheck = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if( dbCheck != SQLITE_OK && dbCheck != SQLITE_BUSY){
        printf("SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    } else {
        printf("SQL executed successfully\n");
    }
}
```

I'm currently using the `sqlite3_exec` on a SQL query string and wanting to use the `callback` function to do my dirty work, but I can easily move things around to use `prepare` and `step`. Callback is currently printing to the screen exactly what I would like put into a string to return to the client, that is `1 2 3 4 5'.

The better and more solid idea I have is as follows:

Create a `char *str` pointer as a global variable and when I set `sql`, set the size of the array to the known number of seats in the plane like so: `str = (char*)calloc(4, sizeof(char));`, then assign each call of callback to an space in `str`. Callback would change as follows:

```
    int tick = 0;
    static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
        str[tick] = argv[0];
        tick++;
        return 0; }
```

However I'm getting the following warning: `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      str[tick] = argv[0];
            ^`

My other idea is to use sprintf to print to a buffer and somehow get that buffer back to the client. However, I don't know how to make a `char` buffer or translate that to a string and I can't find anything to help.

ANYWHO, some assistance would be awesome. I'm beating my head against a wall here.

Comment: Just use [cursors](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5456/sqlite3-stmt-prepared-statement-c-api/19406/reading-data-from-a-cursor).

Comment: @CL. I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by cursors. Like I said in my post I can switch to the `step()` type method like in your example but my issue of storing is still there.

Comment: What does the query return? One row or multiple rows? And are the values strings or numbers?